# Given that $\gamma$ is a unit-speed geodesic on the sphere show that $\gamma \times \gamma' \neq 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $\boldsymbol{\gamma}: [0,A] \to S$ be a unit-speed geodesic, where $S$ is the sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Define $u=\gamma(0) \times \gamma'(0)$. I want to show that $u$ is a non-zero vector.

I know that since $\gamma$ is unit-speed, we must have $||\gamma'(t)||=1$ for all $t \in [0,A]$ and thus we have in particular that $\gamma'(0) \neq0$. However, I'm not sure how I can conclude that $\gamma(0)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sphere is $\{x:x \cdot x = R^2 \}$. $\gamma$ is a curve in this set, so $$\gamma \cdot \gamma = R^2.$$
Differentiating this gives
$$ \gamma \cdot \gamma' = 0. $$
The first equation tells you $\gamma(0) \neq 0$, and then
$$ \lvert \gamma \times \gamma' \rvert^2 = (\gamma \cdot \gamma)(\gamma' \cdot \gamma') - (\gamma \cdot \gamma')^2 = (\gamma \cdot \gamma)(\gamma' \cdot \gamma')  \neq 0. $$